# Use field values on task auto-creation via workflow

Tags: workflow

I have a custom object called `Invoice` with the ability to have tasks/events assigned to it. One of the required fields on the custom object is an `Account` look-up. When a new `Invoice` record is created, I want a task automatically created and assigned to `Account.AccountTeamMember.Name` where `Account.AccountTeamMember.Role = 'Project Manager'`.

I would like to do this in workflow if at all possible, but should have no problem coding it in APEX if required; I have prior Java coding experience. As you are undoubtedly aware, SF suggests that the platform tools be used before resulting to APEX. The issues I've experienced thus far are:

1. Can't create a workflow rule to run on creation of a new object with no filter criteria. As a workaround I simply set this to match `*` for a required field.
2. I cannot specify API names in the `Subject` field when setting the task name. Am I to assume that that dot notation cannot be used?

Answer (score 1):

Best option without resorting to APEX is to use Visual Workflow. Please see the following resources:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Visual_Workflow

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wYVIEA2

Answer (score 0):

It appears code is your only option at this point, there is an Idea out on the [IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bqi6AAC). Another option would be to use an email notification in you want to stay with standard functionality.
Possible workaround: I haven't tried this but can you create a second workflow rule on the task object and if the subject = (whatever you default it to) set it with a formula result?

Comment: I need to track the tasks in a report, so a simple e-mail won't work.

Comment: Updated with a possible workaround.